# How play music in background Java

Tags: java

I have question. I have program where I need to play music in background. Can someone help me? I already searched on internet but no solution worked for me.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573281/how-to-play-a-background-music-when-the-program-run-in-java and then i just found same method as this but nothing worked, then i tried lot of youtube tutorials but nothing worked too

Comment: Add your own non-working code please

Comment: I have made a game in Java sometime ago in which I there is a background music you can find the project in my github repos: https://github.com/syedMohib44/Games-on-Java-and-Misc-Projects/tree/master/WreckIt%20Ralph/src

Comment: Thanks, code from your github worked.

Answer (score 0):

Imports:

```
import java.io.File; 
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
```

Code:

```
try //playing the music
{
    String soundName = "yourAudioFile.wav";    
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(soundName).getAbsoluteFile());
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(audioInputStream);
    clip.start(); //start to play the clip
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    //Do stuff in case of an exception, for example, file not found
}
```