# How to play external sound file in Java

Tags: java, audio, external, javasound, clip

how to play sound in java which not internally saved in java project?
I have tried this code but it only work with the file compiled in java project.. I want to make the sound file directory apart from the java project.

```
private void sound (int s)
{
    try {
      Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
      AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("Music/Sound"+s+".wav"));
      clip.open(inputStream);          
      clip.start();          
    } catch (LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException e) {
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416935/how-to-play-wav-files-with-java

Comment: Use a `File` instead of the `URL`.  And try looking at the JavaDocs for the class in future.

Comment: *"I want to make the sound file directory apart from the java project."*  Are you or the user supplying the sounds?

Comment: i mean the user.. so they can simply put the sounds in 'Music' Directory beside the jar file.