# Is there any java API to play aoudio from an WAV file

Tags: wav

I have extracted the data chunk from an WAV file which I want to play in java. The data is in a byte array. Is there any java API that could do this. Also I have sample rate of the file from the from format chunk.

Comment: Have a look at this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045384/playing-mp3-and-wav-in-java

Comment: And this one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416935/how-to-play-wav-files-with-java