# Error playing audio file from Java via PulseAudio on Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, pulseaudio

The message on the shell is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
    at reprod.ReproducirFichero(reprod.java:16)
    at reprod.main(reprod.java:44)
```

I try to download new drivers for audio, i try to reinstall openJDK 7 and openJRE 7 and also i try to install java 7.

I have proved my code in another computer and it works, the desktop board that i use is an intel d525mw, the audio format that i´m trying to play is .wav.The version of linux that I use is Ubuntu 12.04.3.Please I need help.Thanks

here is party of my code, and i try to play a .wav audio format

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class reprod {

public static void play(){
    try {
        Clip cl = AudioSystem.getClip();

        File f = new File("/home/usr/Desktop/d.wav");
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(f);

        cl.open(ais);

        cl.start();
        System.out.println("playing...");

        while (cl.isRunning())
            Thread.sleep(4000);


        cl.close();
```

the version of linux that I use is Ubuntu 12.04.3

Answer (score 9):

I solved the problem by simply passing the parameter `null` into `AudioSystem.getClip()`.

I don't know why this exception occured, I run this project before on Windows, and it worked... After on Linux and here, it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and found this code to work:

```
File soundFile = new File("/home/usr/Desktop/d.wav");
AudioInputStream soundIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
AudioFormat format = soundIn.getFormat();
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
Clip clip = (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
clip.open(soundIn);
clip.start();
while(clip.isRunning())
{
   Thread.yield();
}
```

The key is in `soundIn.getFormat()`. To quote the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html#getFormat%28%29):

> Obtains the audio format of the sound data in this audio input stream.

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1469572

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that the input file format is wrong somehow.

If you gave us more information (file format, maybe where you got it, code that you use to open the file and how you configured the audio drivers), we might be able to help.

See this question for some code that you can try: [How to play .wav files with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416935/how-to-play-wav-files-with-java)

Comment: the audio format is .wav. I have proved in other computer and it works. I don´t know how cant i configure the audio drivers.