# Java Applet Coding using netbeans

Tags: java

I am a new coder in java and also java applet. I have been using netbeans ide 6.5 as java byte code interpreter. I want to play any formatted audio or video using java applet coding. Is netbeans can do this or is there any extra plugins is needed for this type of coding?? I just install jdk 6 and netbeans 6.5 no extra plugins. Please inform me as simple as possible using java coding that i would play an audio or video file using java applet coding in netbeans ide.

Comment: Netbeans is just an IDE, anything that can be done in Java can be done within Netbeans

Comment: Also, may be of interest to you for playing audio; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416935/how-to-play-wav-files-with-java

Comment: Through native java, you play some audio (and even some video), but for best results you need to look further a broad. You could take a look at [Java Sound] (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/) for examples of audio. I would think applets to restrictive for video - IMHO