# Warning When using AudioPlayer in Java

Tags: java, audio, netbeans

I am using NetBeans IDE and I get this warning when writing a simple class that can play a WAV file:

[image]

As shown in the picture the same message appears at several parts in the sourcecode. Is the Java audio API outdated? If so, what can I adjust in my code to get rid of this warning?

```
public class Sound{

private AudioStream sound;

public Sound(String location){

    try{
    InputStream file = new FileInputStream(location);
    sound = new AudioStream(file);
    }
    catch(IOException error){
        //error
    }

}

public void play(){

    AudioPlayer.player.start(sound);

}

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't build your application on the internal API functionality.  It's not a concrete API, and as the warning states, can disappear at a moment's notice.  It's also the same reason why Javadoc is scarce for that specific class.

Comment: What alternative is there that has the same functionality?

Comment: The `javax.sound.sampled` package is what you're looking for. See, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416935/how-to-play-wav-files-with-java

Comment: Take a look at [javax.sound](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info); linked is the Stack Overflow tag for it.

Comment: Thnaks! This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Those comments can be answers...