# Playing .wav continuously in java: Invalid Format Exception

Tags: java, audio

I want to play a .wav file continuously in Java. I found some code, but I can't make it work.

```
String fileName = "res/sound/buz.wav";
File file = new File(fileName);
AudioInputStream ais;
try {
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
    clip.open(ais);
    clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);

} catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException
        | LineUnavailableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get an Invalid Format Exception on clip.open(ais):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
    at launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:59)
```

I checked and file is created correctly and exists. So, what is the problem with my code?

If it matters, I'm working on Linux, but this should work on both Linux and Windows...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416935/how-to-play-wav-files-with-java - full example- see accepted answer

Comment: Shouldn't "`|`" be "`||`"?

Comment: And can you add a command in the code what line 59 is?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy I liked this code because it's short. I will try the accepted answer now

Comment: @moffeltje Well eclipse says that "|" is accepted. clip.open(ais); is at line 59.

Comment: @MaVRoSCy How do I play this sound continuously? If you can write that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution

```
    try{
        File file = new File (fileName);
        AudioClip clip = Applet.newAudioClip(file.toURL());
        clip.loop();
        clip.stop();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I can play a .wav file in a loop and stop it. That's what I wanted. And the code is very short.