# Playing wav file in java

Tags: java, audio

Im trying to make sound effects for my game but i couldn't achieve to play it yet.
I have looked up everywhere but everytime that i try to do what i see i always have this error:

```
javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input file
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
at pong.Pong.loadResources(Pong.java:114)
at pong.Pong.<init>(Pong.java:69)
at pong.Pong.main(Pong.java:34)
```

This the code that i try to run:

```
try {   
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("score.wav"));
        AudioFormat format = audioInputStream.getFormat();
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
        clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        clip.open(audioInputStream);
        clip.start();

    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Just to be sure, i placed the same named same wav file under directly the project folder, src folder, res folder too. I would like to have it opened from res folder by the way but first thing i have to do is just fixing the code to play the sound. Then i can work with the path declaration. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try putting in `System.out.println(new File("score.wav").exits());` into your code, I suspect the file does not exist where you think it does

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    File file = new File("clip.wav");
    if(file.exists()) {
        try {
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);

            AudioFormat audioFormat = audioInputStream.getFormat();

            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);

            SourceDataLine sourceLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            sourceLine.open(audioFormat);

            sourceLine.start();

            int nBytesRead = 0;
            byte[] abData = new byte[128000];
            while (nBytesRead != -1) {
                try {
                    nBytesRead = audioInputStream.read(abData, 0, abData.length);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (nBytesRead >= 0) {
                    sourceLine.write(abData, 0, nBytesRead);
                }
            }

            sourceLine.drain();
            sourceLine.close();

        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        System.err.println("The selected file doesn't exist!");
    }
```

It works fine.
If you are using Eclipse (I don't know how it works with others IDEs) make sure you place the file in the project's root folder.

Solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416935/how-to-play-wav-files-with-java) question.

Comment: I have tried that solution too and it's not working, still i get the same error exception throw

Comment: Which operative system do you use and which version of java?

Comment: @TolgaŞen
Also try with other wav files, maybe your file is corrupted.

Comment: I use windows8.1 and java7, when i try with the other files it still throws the same error. I suppose nothing wrong with the file

Comment: I'm using "java8 update 73" and the code works fine, I don't know but maybe it's a bug of your java version, try to update java if you can.

Comment: I have updated java to 1.8 also and its still throwing the same error. Do we have another way to do this? I mean playing a sound shouldn't be this complicated...