# How to play a wav file using Java?

Tags: java, wav

I would like to play a wav file and after I googled it I found this script but it doesn't work.
(It didn't throw any exceptions nor have compiling problems)

```
 import java.io.File;
 import films.Film;
 import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
 import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

 public class MusicStorage {

 /**
 * Opens a wav file and plays it
 * @param args
 */
public void play(Film song) {
    try {
        Clip sound = AudioSystem.getClip();

        sound.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(song.getClip())));

        sound.start();

        while (sound.isRunning())
            Thread.sleep(1000);

        sound.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Whatever" + e);
    }
  }
}

import audio.MusicStorage;
import films.Film;

public class Aplication {

private static Film gladiator = new Film("Gladiator", "gladiator.wav");
private static MusicStorage storage = new MusicStorage();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    storage.play(gladiator);
}
}

public class Film {

private String name;
private String clip;

public Film(String name, String clip) {
    this.name = name;
    this.clip = clip;
}

public String getClip() {
    return clip;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
}
```

I have added all the code that I have so I hope it would be clear to solve my problem

Comment: where is your Main method where you call play(Film song)? Please show all associated code

Comment: removing while(sound.isRunning()) should work !

Comment: Doing nothing would be expected. There is nothing in the code you provided which should run anything.

Comment: @KhairulBasarRofi Why do you think so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play .wav files with java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416935/how-to-play-wav-files-with-java)

Comment: may be when the loop is running it's stopping playing the audio file as it's sleeping and the thread will be paused just.  @CharlesMcKelvey

Comment: yeah, its now fixed after removing that loop. Thanks @KhairulBasarRofi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the while loop from your code and it should be fixed. The while loop is making the thread sleep so it can't play the audio file.

```
public void play(Film song) {
    try {
        Clip sound = AudioSystem.getClip();

        sound.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(song.getClip())));

        sound.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Whatever" + e);
    }
  }
}
```