# How to pass data as Byte from a WAV file to sound card in java

Tags: java, wav

[image]

how create stream between WAV file and sound card ?

Comment: That depends of the Sound Card, what you trying to send, signals or the file? files you use stream, for sound signals you need to check your sound card api

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416935/how-to-play-wav-files-with-java?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I need to create decoder (Wav , Mp3 ...) ,It is not allowed to use decoder Ready