# A buzzer system using java, clip wont play

Tags: java, microcontroller

So im trying to make a buzzer system for my club at school (Sciencebowl) because an actual one costs like 500 dollars.
Everything else seems to work but when I run the code what I think is happening is that the clip will play over and over restarting each time and the thread that it is in stops before it can actually play.
Im using a button externally that ive hooked up to a micro controller

this is code that grabs those 1s and 0s from a microcontroller

```
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.*;
public class Microreader {


    private SerialPort port;
    int i = 2;

    public Microreader() { 
        SerialPort[] ports = SerialPort.getCommPorts();
        port = ports[1]; // Modify this to select the correct port
        System.out.println(port);
        //grabs the port and store it in port
         
    }

    public SerialPort getSerialPort() { 
        return port;
//this allows me to use the port
    }
    
    public void openPort(SerialPort tport) { 
        if (tport.openPort()) {
            System.out.println("Port opened.");
            int baudRate = 115200;
            tport.setBaudRate(baudRate);
            tport.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_SEMI_BLOCKING, 100, 0);
//opening up the port (its COM5 btw im using an arduino)
    }
    

}
public char readPortValues() {
    
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1]; // 40% of this part is stole nbut from trial and error I
                                         // dont think the error is here
        int numRead = port.readBytes(readBuffer, readBuffer.length); // Read data into buffer

        if (numRead > 0) { //just to make sure it isnt some weird negatve voodoo
            char receivedChar = (char) readBuffer[0];
            
            if (receivedChar == '1' || receivedChar == '0') { //prettu sure theres no point in this 
                                                              //conditional ill probably get rid of 
                                                              //it
                System.out.println(receivedChar); //I print out 1s and 0s a little redundantly
                                                  //they say redundancy is good but... not here
                                                  //.....probably
                return receivedChar;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Received an unexpected character: " + receivedChar);
                return receivedChar;
                
            }
        }
        else { 
            System.out.println("no valid value");
            return 'x';
        }
    
}
}
```

The code that plays the sound

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.IOException; 

  
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream; 
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem; 
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip; 
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException; 
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException; 
  
public class soundplayer 
{ 
  
    // to store current position 
    Long currentFrame; 
    Clip clip; 
      
    // current status of clip 
    String status; 
      
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream; 
    static String filePath; 
  
    // constructor to initialize streams and clip 
    public soundplayer(String filePath) 
        throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, 
        IOException, LineUnavailableException  
    { 
        soundplayer.filePath = filePath;
        // create AudioInputStream object 
        audioInputStream =  
                AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(filePath).getAbsoluteFile()); 
          
        // create clip reference 
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip(); 
          
        // open audioInputStream to the clip 
        clip.open(audioInputStream); 
        
    } 
  

      
    // Work as the user enters his choice 
      

      
    // Method to play the audio 
    public void play()  
    { 
        //start the clip 
        clip.start(); 
          
        status = "play"; 
    } 
     // Method to stop the audio 
     public void stop() throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, 
     IOException, LineUnavailableException  
     { 
         currentFrame = 0L; 
         clip.stop(); 
         clip.close(); 
     } 
}
```

putting it all together

```
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException; 
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.*;


public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws 
    UnsupportedAudioFileException, 
        IOException, LineUnavailableException {
        int i = 0;
        int g = 0;
        int k = 0;
        soundplayer clip = new soundplayer("D:\\Working Zone\\RPReplay_Final1701075140.wav"); //the clip vkia a file path on my computer
        Microreader value = new Microreader(); //this just rmakes the microreader object
        SerialPort tport = value.getSerialPort(); //this gets the port back
        value.openPort(tport);
        //clip.play(); I tested the clip here on its own and added my for loop delay stretegy
                      // it worked as intended
        while(g == 0) { 

        
        char tvalue = value.readPortValues();

        if (tvalue == '1') {  // plays the sound if a 1 is read
            if (i == 0) {  //prevents the sound from playing over and over I just want it to play  
                           //once
                System.out.println("1");
            }
            else{
            
            clip.play(); //right here the clip im pretty sure plays but is ended due to the 
                         //"thread" ending ( I think) 
                         //I only want the clip to play once per button press, ( i have a button set                   
                         //up externally) i dont want two cleips to play at the same time 
                         //but I dont want the program to run jus tonce  iwant to to run
                         //until I manually shut it off
            
            
            i = 0;
            
            
            

        }
    }
        else if (tvalue == 0) { 
            if (i == 1) { 
                System.out.println("0"); //stops the sound if a 0 is read unless it has already                
                                         //stopped
            }
            else{
            clip.stop();
            
            i = 1;
            }

        }
    }
    }
}
```

I tried using a for to loop to delay it but thatt just printed out some humongous google plex level number

```
 if (tvalue == '1') { 
            if (i == 0) { 
                System.out.println("1");
            }
            else{
            
            clip.play();
            
            
            i = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < 20000; k++) { 
                System.out.println();
            }
```

ive also tried making a new thread like

```
Thread playThread = new Thread(() -> {
                clip.play();
            });
            playThread.start();

            // should pause this bit while concurrently alloweing the clip to play
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000); // Delay for 5 seconds (adjust as needed)
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

but it still doesnt play, Im not a great programmer, evidently, but I also dont want to spend 500 dollars on a box that makes a noise..... also just wanted an excuse to make something. help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to test this stuff. If your theory is 'it is due to the thread ending' then sleep the thread (`Thread.sleep`). There is no need to make a busy-loop. If that helps - great, apply it. If that does nothing - great, you have disproved your theory.

Comment: Depending on how exactly you wired up your key you might actually run into a "bouncing" issue and need to add a debouncer (either physical/electronical or in software). That means that the switch goes from "pressed" to "unpressed" back to "pressed" real quickly, so to your software it might look like many independent key presses one after another.

Comment: Here's one [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416935/how-to-play-wav-files-with-java/74965929#74965929) that plays a WAV file.

Comment: In general, write it so that you can plug the 'button' - replace it real easy with just hitting enter on the keyboard. This in passing also tests GenerousBadger's debouncing theory (quite a plausible one) - if it doesn't happen when you just press enter you know the problem lies with input processing (such as needing to debounce it), not with turning 'yes, button pressed!' into audio.