# Changing sound output source with python or shell

Tags: python, windows, powershell

So I'm trying to change the computer's sound output with either python or shell, for example from headphones to speakers (I am using Windows).
I've tried looking at bunch of places but couldn't find an answer, does anyone know how maybe?

Thanks :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What has your [prior research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) turned up?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting playback device by executing a batch file / powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838514/setting-playback-device-by-executing-a-batch-file-powershell-script)

Comment: I'll take a look at this, thank you :)

Comment: There's a module for that : https://github.com/frgnca/AudioDeviceCmdlets
Otherwise, from the link of previous commenter, the second answer suggest going with Nircmd.exe, which you easily use from the command line of your choice to do that (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52901108/934946). 

I'd abstain from using AutoHotkey unless you already have it, of course, simply because it's the less practical of the bunch (Powershell > Nircmd > AuthoHotkey).